# turn on Windows 7 `Windows keys`

Tags: windows-7

At work, I have a Windows 7 PC, but some features are missing, like some shortcuts Windows+Tab and others. Can anyone tell me if there is a registry setting to disable this feature, or a stopped service?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i just went to Control Panel\All Control Panel Items\Personalization\Window Color and Appearance, unchecked and re-checked the checkbox "Enable transparency" and now it works fine

Answer (score 3):

If I'm not mistaken, the Win+Tab shortcut you mention is a feature of Aero, which may be disabled if your work machine has low-end graphics hardware or you are using a virtual machine or RDP session.

This [article](http://www.mydigitallife.info/2009/01/13/how-to-turn-on-and-enable-aero-in-windows-7-enable-aero-peek/) should help you determine if Aero is your issue.

Answer (score 1):

At work I have a win 7 pc, but some features are missing
if there is a registry setting to disable this feature

so you want to be able to see everything
It may not have been loaded if its a work computer.
just click start button and search for what you think is missing and see if you can turn it on but only if you have Admin rights.

Comment: I am an local admin

Answer (score 1):

### Easy Aero Fix

In **Start**, type **Aero** and click **Find and fix problems with transparency and other visual effects**.

Answer (score 0):

may be you do not have the **"Desktop Experience"** feature installed. also, after check/install this feature, you should go to the **System Panel** and run the graphic card validationg process, then win7 will setup the Aero for you.

Answer (score 0):

There is a group policy setting to disable Windows key shortcuts. That is something which is configured by your system administrator. There is also a policy to specifically disable windows flip (Win+Tab). You may want to talk to your system administrator and see if they could enable those settings.